# Windows 8 Consumer Preview broken download?

Tags: windows, download, windows-8-preview

I have downloaded Windows 8 Consumer preview,but when i was downloading(with free download manager) it there was a power failure and it got stopped at 50% and again when i turned on my computer and i resumed the download,it went fine and i got downloaded the whole .iso file.
But when i tried to installing it it gives an error at '49%' saying something went wrong and it stops,i know i had a power failure when downloading it when it was at 50%.
I checked the 'SHA1' of the iso image from that from the windows website they were different.
And i cant download the whole file again i have execeeded the bandwidth limit on downloading from my ISP. Can i get it working again? Thanks for the responses

Comment: I have 50%, do I have 100%? No, start over again.

Answer (score 6):

If the SHA-1 is different it means that your file is corrupted. The only solution is to download it again.